# Cant Update SQL data using this code, checked code so many times

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote this code to update entry in my sql table, but i don't what is wrong.

Here is my form

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <center>
     Alumni_ID :
     <input type="text" name="valueh">
     <br>
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
     <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="contact details">
     <input type="text" name="details" placeholder="details">
     <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="address">
     <input type="submit" value="update data">
  </center>
</form>
```

And this is php page,

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "tssolutions";
   $ab = $_POST['name'];
   $bc = $_POST['phone'];
   $cd = $_POST['details'];
   $de = $_POST['address'];
   $posted = $_POST['valueh'];

   //create connection
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   //check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   //echo "connected successfully";
   $sql = " UPDATE phone SET name='".$ab."', phone='".$bc."', details='".$cd."', address='".$de."' WHERE name = '".$posted."' ";
   if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "<hr>";
      echo "<h3 class='w3-center' style='text-color:black'>Record Successfully Updated</h3>";
   } else {
      echo "<hr>";
      echo "<h3 class='w3-center' style='text-color:black'>Error While Updating, Try Again</h3>";
   }
   mysqli_close($conn);
} ?>
```

Both the code are on same page Update.php, i wish to send alumni_id so that i can update that record where alumni_id = name in table phone, and then send new values of the row .

Comment: Do not munge SQL query strings with values.  Instead, learn how to properly use parameters.  Munging query strings can and does result in unexplained query errors.

Comment: More concerning is that concatenating SQL strings instead of using the parameterization support in your programming language or library of choice is that you open yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Maybe you have an input value with a single quote in it. Using parameters would save you from that problem, as well as saving you from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You need to learn to indent your code. That's going to be horrible to maintain later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to name the submit button

Instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="update data">
```

Try this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="update data">
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug your code you can echo your SQL statement

```
     echo $sql = "UPDATE phone SET name='".$ab."', phone='".$bc."', details='".$cd."', address='".$de."' WHERE name = '".$posted."';
```

You can then see if you have correct syntax and your values are sent correctly

Comment: thank you , it help me to redefine, next piece of code. That was a handy trick.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, maybe this helps

```
$sql = " UPDATE phone SET `name` ='$ab', `phone` ='$bc', `details` ='$cd', `address`='$de' WHERE `name` = '$posted' ";
```